# Stopping auto refresh from the loaded page

Tags: jquery

Page "Main" uses `setInterval` in combination with `jQuery.load` to load content from "Sub" page.

I need to be able to stop auto refresh from happening, if "Sub" page contains a specific flag.

In other words, the "Sub" page should be reloaded until it tells Main to stop auto refresh.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the flag in the callback handler for the load event and clear the interval timer if the flag is found.

```
  var timer = setInterval( function() {
      $('#sub').load('/example/foo', function() {
          if ($('#sub:contains("flag")').length) {
             clearInterval(timer);
          }
      });
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `clearInterval` method.

```
var x = setInterval(myFunc, 5000);
clearInterval(x);
```

If you can provide the code you're using we'll be better able to tailor this to the logic you're using.

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

example:

```
var test=self.setInterval("func()",1000);
// later
clearInterval(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
setInterval(function(){yourfunction()});
```

dont add the interval or put a .stop()

```
setInterval(function(){yourfunction()}).stop();
```

Comment: `setInerval` returns a number it has no `stop` method. -1 for totally wrong answer anyway.